# HorizontalScrollView - Make a gallery with pagination

Tags: android, pagination, horizontalscrollview

I want to have in my registration view a slide of images with pagination, so it'd look something like this (the first screen):

[image]

As you can see there, there's slide of images that you can swipe and also a pagination under the button. But I can't find really any useful material on how to do it.
Am I choosing the right widget? And how can I do this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the official android API

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging